# Past Subjunctive Sentence

Tags: verbs, past-tense, subjunctive-mood, clauses, sentence-meaning

*If we started now we would be in time (but we cannot start now)*

This is an example sentence in my grammar book for past subjunctive used after *If*. The sentence sounds to me a suggestion rather than unreality. I don't understand how the sentence is expressing improbability or unreality?

Comment: It's conjecture—a hypothesis (*unreality*, in your terminology).

Comment: The subjunctive tense *itself* expresses improbability or unreality. If the speaker didn't think that starting now was unlikely or impossible, they would have said *If we start now, we will be on time*.

Comment: Subjunctive is not a tense, but a mood. I any case, that is irrelevant since English lost the subjunctive mood in earlier stages of the language. Instead, subjunctive is treated as a clause type headed by a plain form of the verb, as in "It is vital that I **be** kept informed". The odd-ball is the "were", as in "I wish I were rich", now called 'irrealis' rather than the ill-named 'past subjunctive'.

Comment: “If we started now” seems internally contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

> *If we started now we would be in time (but we cannot start now).*

The bracketed bit prevents the usual analysis of the sentence, so I've ignored it for the purposes of this answer.

There's no subjunctive clause in your example. Subjunctive clauses are headed by a plain (infinitive) form of the verb. Some speakers (wrongly) claim that "If I were you" is past subjunctive, but even that doesn't match your example.

"Started" is actually a modal preterite used to mark modality rather than past time. The preterite suggests that we may not start now. There is a choice here between present tense “start” and preterite “started”, which illustrates an important distinction between two kinds of conditional construction, **open** (with "start) and **remote** (with "started").

The open type typically leaves it open as to whether the condition is or will be fulfilled.

The remote type, by contrast, presents our leaving as somewhat less likely than the open type. It would generally be preferred where our current plans or inclinations are to leave later.

Answer (score 0):

> "If we started now we would be in time"

In the context of being unable to start now, the sentence is the same as "If we could fly, we would be on time." Our ability to start is the same as our ability to fly, i.e. nil. What follows "we would be on time" is fantasy. (Or as it is often described "irrealis" - an unreality.)

Answer (score -3):

> If we started now we would be in time (but we cannot start now)

Like you, I disagree with the book. There is no implication that we cannot start now.

Nevertheless it *is* the past subjunctive.

If we start now, we will be in time. (present indicative)

If we started now we would be in time. (past subjunctive)

**Examples**

> Mary: Are we ready to start yet?
>
> John: What's the hurry?
>
> Mary: If we start now we will be in time. (indicative)
>
> John: Oh, okay then.

> Mary: Are we ready to start yet?
>
> John: What's the hurry?
>
> Mary: If we started now we would be in time. (subjunctive)
>
> John: Oh, okay then.

In neither of the above cases is it impossible for us to start.

Comment: You didn't get my question. The sentence is *If we started now we would be in time* and in a bracket beside the sentence meaning to it is given *but we cannot start now*, I think it tells starting now is not possible, but if they had started now they would have been in time. Isn't it what the sentence is implying?

Comment: One more thing I would like to mention. My books says *the past subjunctive* is used after *if* to express unreality and improbability in the present.